# Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 2941

Tags: react-native-firebase

I have this error "Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 2941. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code: ". It's because i try to read like 1400 documents in firestore. I do something like this:

```
array.map(userUid => {
        var docRef = db.collection('users').doc(userUid);
        docRef.get().then(doc => {
          ...
        })
})
```

Here array is an array with 1400 users's uid. I don't know how to handle this error, do you have any idea ?

Infos:

- react native: 0.61.1
- react-native-firebase: 6.4.0
- Bug on IOS simulator didn't try on Android.

Comment: "Please report" means it is a bug with React Native and you should report it to the devs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480089/how-to-avoid-excessive-number-of-pending-callbacks-501-error-during-images-do