# How to avoid "Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501" error during images download in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, react-redux, react-native-fs

I need to download a collection of images on button press. Currently, I'm doing it this way using `react-native-fs`:

```
const downloadImageItem = async (imgUrl, id) => {
  const path = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${id}.jpg`;

  RNFS.downloadFile({
    fromUrl: imgUrl,
    toFile: path,
  });
};
```

```
const downloadImages = async (items) => {
  for (const item of items) {
    if (item.images.length) {
      await downloadImageItem(item.images[0].thumb, item.images[0].id);
    }
  }
  return Promise.resolve();
};
```

Calling the function from my reducer for 3 types of items:

```
await downloadImages(items_one);
await downloadImages(items_two);
await downloadImages(items_three);
```

My issue is that sometimes I receive an error message that says:
***Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501***

Is there a better way of doing the same thing, so that the error does not appear?

Answer (score 9):

A similar [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27483) was opened on the `react-native` repository in December 2019, it still hasn't been closed or addressed but I think you may find this [comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27483#issuecomment-594240966) useful.

The problem being described there is that queueing too many `Promise` calls can be problematic. The commenter suggested using a `Promise` utility function called `Promise.map()` which has concurrency control out of the box, from the [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) library.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I keep getting ```TypeError: Promise.map is not a function``` error message. Even though I made an import ```import * as Promise from 'bluebird'```. And refactored the download function as follows:
 ```const downloadImages = async (items) => {
  await Promise.map(items, (item) => downloadImageItem(item), {
    concurrency: 200,
  });
  return Promise.resolve();
}```

Comment: Did you install the package correctly? Either npm or yarn. Here's the [docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) for the `Promise.map()` function.

Comment: Trying to use it, but can't make it work. If you can, please take a look at: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/1652

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using await inside for, try using `for await`

```
for await (variable of iterable) {
  sentence
}
```

```
const downloadImages = async (items) => {
  for await(const item of items) {
    if (item.images.length) {
      downloadImageItem(item.images[0].thumb, item.images[0].id);
    }
  }
  return Promise.resolve();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; to me, it was because of a long chain of promises I had inside a component.

Once I moved the function to a different file the warning disappeared.